# Defining dynamic Form ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to define dynamic form id for the following example form.

The following code doesn't give me the result I want. for example, instead of `<form id="form1">`,
I get this result   : `<form id='form''1'>`

How should I write it so it gives me the result I want? Thanks !!

```
<?php 

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($subject)) {

    echo "<form id='form'.'{$data['productID']}' method='post' action=' ' data-checktable='{$data['productID']}'>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='SelectAll'>All";
        echo "<label><input type='checkbox'  class='selector' value='{$data['product1']}'>" . $data['product1']."</label>";
        echo "<label><input type='checkbox'  class='selector' value='{$data['product2']}'>" . $data['product2']."</label>";
        echo "</form>";
         }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to Change it to

```
echo "<form id='form{$data['productID']}' method='post' action=' ' data-checktable='{$data['productID']}'>";
```

i.e. remove the extra `'.'` between the word `form` and the ID you wanted.